# setValue to QUERY() formula doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Part of my spreadsheet's script runs the following piece of code:

```
temp.getRange(1, 1).setValue("=QUERY(data!A1:H125, \"Select A\")");
```

As you might expect, this puts `=QUERY(data!A1:H125, "Select A")` into the A1 
cell BUT the formula gives an error `(#NAME, error: Unknown range name data!A1)`. 
I know the formula is correct because if I copy and paste it into the neighboring
 cell everything works fine. I do have a sheet called 'data' and it is full of
data in the range A1:H125.

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on the Google support forums. The setFormula function is required rather than the setValue function.

ie. `temp.getRange(1, 1).setFormula("=QUERY(data!A1:H125, \"Select A\")");` should work