# Add new row and fill with self labling formula

Tags: google-apps-script, import, google-sheets, callable, newrow

I'm trying to use `importrange()` to group all of my Google form results. I would like to add at the top of the Google form response sheet a row with, `URL, Workbook name, Sheet name, and Date code` to easily copy and paste into a master workbook.

I am trying to work toward an easy to make masters workbook which will populate with all of the students results, something that will be easy for other teachers to use and sort data.

I have been learning coding for less than a month and have put together pieces from of other's work, but am getting error messages

> "ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined.

I attached the Google form results with sheet labels in second row. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lW8xkSbrgDm-UG83nCnp_9p3NWvP5bnlaCpENDCgQd4/edit?usp=sharing

I currently have working and `getUrl()`, `sheetName()`, and `tabName()`,  and an `onOpen()` `addRow()`.  I can not get the formula's into the new cells.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name:"Add New 2nd Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = 1; 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");
  cell.setFormula("getUrl");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
  cell.setFormula("sheetName");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("C2");
  cell.setFormula("tabName");
}

function getUrl() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
  var url = '';
  url += SS.getUrl();
  url += '#gid=';
  url += ss.getSheetId(); 
  return url;
}

function sheetName() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
}

function tabName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = ss.getActiveRange().getSheet();
  return ss.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formulas should start with `=` and custom functions should have parenthesis, so instead of

```
cell.setFormula("getUrl");
```

the following should be wrote:

```
cell.setFormula("=getUrl()");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
'cell.setFormula()' didn't work used 
'cell.setValue("=sheetName()");'

Comment: Using setValue() to pass formulas isn't reliable (see [setValue to QUERY() formula doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3613674/1595451)) What do you mind byd "didn't work"? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Tried 'cell.setFormula()' no error this time 
Thanks for the tip.

Comment: When I tried this code in a second tab I received the error message "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid"

Comment: @ChrisShortreed: The question include several functions. Which one are you talking about? Is the error shown on a cell?